# Swipe back function in IOS App

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am working on an application in Xamarin. The iOS feature of swipe back is not working and I don't know how to figure it out and fix it. Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Where can I find this feature in my app code files and. how to enable or disable it?

Comment: You mean interactivePopGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: Was the code I provided what you were looking for?

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan Yes GestureRecognize

Comment: Can u paste your code here that u tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, in this Delegate we can use an event called `ShouldBegin()` to enable or disable the system back feature:

```
public class MyGestureDelegate : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    public override bool ShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then assign the `Delegate` to it:

```
NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new MyGestureDelegate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: Not exactly but yah this is somehow in the right direction